# Big Sur Update Leads to Multiple Load Error Rails Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, development-environment, macos-big-sur

After updating to Big Sur, my ruby (2.6.3) on rails (5.2.1) application repeatedly has LoadError when running `rails s` or `rails db:migrate`.

I have tried uninstall and reinstall rails multiple time but it will only work 1 or 2 times before encountering LoadError again.

Here are some samples of the errors (Note that they are different)

```console
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require': cannot load such file -- new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sinatra/transaction_namer (LoadError)

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.8.0.360/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_merchant.rb (LoadError)

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-6.8.0.360/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/typhoeus.rb (LoadError)

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffaker/company (LoadError)
```

---

**Update:** currently trying installing rails via rvm to see if this consistent error goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use Apple's Ruby installation. That installation exists *solely* for internal use by Apple itself.

My *guess* is that the System Integrity Protection keeps deleting and/or restoring stuff that you changed in the system protected directories.

For more information, see for example

- [macOS 10.15 Catalina Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes#Scripting-Language-Runtimes)
- [PSA: Do not use system Ruby](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby)
- [Why you shouldn't use the System Ruby](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby)
- [If possible, do not use the ruby system version on Mac OSX](https://egel.github.io/2018/11/10/if-possible-do-not-use-the-ruby-system-version-on-mac-osx.html)

Comment: Thanks! I think your guess is correct. I finally get the rbenv to work and then install the gems on rbenv path and no more such issues.