# Big Sur - Ruby - Cannot load such file — Interrupted system call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rbenv, macos-big-sur

After upgrading to Big Sur I am getting errors running my Ruby server rotating through different files either with

```
cannot load such file --
```

or

```
Interrupted system call --
```

These errors rotate various files each time I run bundle exec rackup.  I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling RVM, XCode Command Line Tools, and even tried switching to rbenv.  Same outcome.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am having literally the same error as described on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65084827/big-sur-update-leads-to-multiple-load-error-rails-ruby but using rvm and rbenv don't fix it.

Comment: Any update on this? I am also facing the same random file load errors.

Comment: I had similar problems using rbenv.sh caused by Avast anti-virus. Temporarily disable the file shields and then it will work, and you can re-enable them after.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to get solved by uninstalling Kaspersky.

Also, it seems that the ruby applications are not the only ones facing this issue.
There are other security solutions too, eg. Avira.

https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1710

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44509

Comment: I had same issues with Sophos Home. Disabled all protection from the dashboard and I was able to install.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this problem for an `rbenv` ruby installation after noticing a similar-ish issue listed at the end of the [ruby-build wiki](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#cannot-load-such-file----auto_gem). Adding `MAKE_OPTS=-j1` finally worked, though it took much longer; The whole build ran with one process. The final command I used (though I don't know if calling `ruby-build` directly was necessary):

```sh
MAKE_OPTS=-j1 RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-readline-dir=$(brew --prefix readline) --with-libyaml-dir=$(brew --prefix libyaml)" \
  ruby-build --verbose 2.6.6 ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/
# to hook it up with rbenv:
rbenv rehash
```

I know this isn't your exact problem, but perhaps re-installing ruby would help.

Comment: Thanks I ended up switching back to rvm and reinstalled and I seem to see the error less frequently but still intermittently.  Any idea if there is a similar option to install via rvm on a single process?

Comment: I was able to re-install ruby with the make option of -j1 by using export rvm_make_flags="-j1" in my user .rvmrc file and unfortunately after reinstalling ruby-2.6.4 and rebuilding my gemset, I still get the cannot load such file error when running rackup.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in `brew install lima`

this may not look like answer, but running up that command again and again `brew install lima` I kept getting different errors, I ran that command 7-8 times, and was able to finally install lima.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete resolution yet, but we did find out that the issue seems specific to the newrelic-ruby-agent and have opened an issue (https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent/issues/528) with them to do further investigation.

As a workaround, we are able to run locally by setting `NEW_RELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=false` in the env.list

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Avira solved the problem I was having with `rbenv install 3.0.0` on macOS 11.2. (See [ruby-build #1710 (comment)](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1710#issuecomment-774549963).) Thanks to @alex for the [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66020819/6732127).